# Turn off Eclipse auto correction in "program arguments"

Tags: java, eclipse

With the new version of Eclipse Oxygen, I found an annoying auto-correction
for the "program arguments" editor window, which can be accessed through the arguments tab of the "Run configuration" for running or debugging code. For example, if I input two dash characters "--", then they are automatically converted into a long-single-dash character "—", after I hit the enter key. I have tried to turn off spelling check, but it did not fix it.

I am using a MAC book pro, with Eclipse IDE for Java Developers, Version: Oxygen.1a Release (4.7.1a), Build id: 20171005-1200.

Comment: Sounds like a OS setting. Check out [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/555628/how-to-stop-mac-to-convert-typing-double-dash-to-emdash). Seems someone [posted this as a bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=519109) and it was concluded to be MAC-specific

Comment: Thank you @VinceEmigh! It is a MAC thing. I have fixed it by running the following in the terminal, as pointed out in the first post in Vince's comment. 
`defaults write -g NSAutomaticDashSubstitutionEnabled 0`